# How to create a python egg? and spark submit it

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, python-3.7, spark-submit, egg

I must be doing a wrong assumption because I don't find a way to solve this. I want to spark-submit a .egg file, that should be:  `spark-submit --py-files mypkg.egg main.py argv1 argv2` , that only needs the .egg file. But when I execute this, I get:

```
 python: can't open file 'C:/Users/israel/Desktop/spark_python_maven/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

After researching I set a folder structure, a **init**.py file , and added path/to/main.py to the spark-submit, then the error changed to :

```
File "C:/Users/israel/Desktop/spark_python_maven/src/mypkg/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.mypkg.data_layer import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The only way I found to make this work is to remove the **init**.py and set the path to the main.py and the others .py files, so I need both the .egg and the .py files when I was expecting to only need the .egg file.

my main.pylooks like:

```
import os
import sys
from src.mypkg.data_layer import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    print("hello world!")
```

My setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mypkg',
    version='0.1',
    packages = find_packages('src'),  # include all packages under src
    package_dir = {'':'src'}   # tell distutils packages are under src
)
```

My init.py looks like :

```
from src.mypkg import *
from .mypkg import *
```

My project structure looks like:

[image]

Where setup.py is at the same level as src, and init.py is at the same level as mypkg.

What I want to do is create an .egg file that has all I need to spark-submit with argvs. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, have you already found a solution? I would also be interested in a solution.